# How to add a LinkedIn profile badge on personal websites?

Tags: linkedin-api, profile, badge

I want to add a badge that will navigate to my **LinkedIn profile**. I've been searching online but what they said to be **"Edit Profile"** button doesn't seem to exist.

Is it because They are using **premium**? Or if it could be done using **basic account**?

Comment: this is a off-topic question, you should ask this kind of question on meta (https://meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I'm not asking about how to add a stackexchange badge on LinkedIn, which has already been answered on meta. This question is only related LinkedIn

Comment: Edit Profile>Edit public profile>create profile badge.. From there you can copy the javascirpt and html snippets which you can then add to your websites code.. Unfortunately for me the badge doesn't show up even after i do this. It just displays my name as a link to my profile. Is anyone facing same problem?

Answer (score 0):

As I commented on your post, this is an **off-topic** question and you should ask on I think on https://meta.stackexchange.com/.

but these are the steps which you can create a badge for Linkedin:

1.Log into your LinkedIn account.
2.Hover over the Profile tab with your mouse or pointer on LinkedIn's main menu bar at the top of the page and select Edit Profile.
3.In the top section, look below your picture to where your profile URL is listed. ...
4.The Public Profile page should be open. On the right-hand side of the page you'll see "Your Public Profile URL" and below that "Customize Your Public Profile." Underneath that, you'll see "Your Public Profile Badge." Click on Create a Public Profile Badge link.

5.The LinkedIn badge page opens with a variety of graphics to choose from. Next to each badge is a box with code. Select the badge you like and copy the corresponding code. When you click in the code box, all the code will highlight. Right click on your mouse and choose Copy.

6.Go to the web page, blog or another page where you want to display your LinkedIn badge and paste the code you copied. Put your cursor in the spot you want the badge to appear. Right click and select Paste. Make sure you're in the text editor or the code will appear on your webpage or blog and not the badge. Click on save and check that your badge is appearing correctly.

Comment: There is no such thing called "Edit Profile". Can you show me a snapshot of where it is?